# Blazor StateHasChanged() does not work after switching pages (async)

Tags: c#, async-await, blazor, blazor-server-side

StateHasChanged() works normally when working without changing pages. However, if you go back to another page and do the same thing again, it doesn't work. The value in the variable enters normally, so if you do an event (click the button), the desired output is made again. I think StateHasChanged() doesn't know the change. Could this be due to async?

```
<div>
  @foreach (var noti in PushNotifications.notifications)
  {
    <p>@noti</p>
  }
</div>

@code {
...
  async public void subscribe()
  {
    AppContext.SetSwitch(
         "System.Net.Http.SocketsHttpHandler.Http2UnencryptedSupport",
         true);
    SocketsHttpHandler handler = new SocketsHttpHandler();

    var httpClient = new HttpClient(handler)
      {
        DefaultVersionPolicy = HttpVersionPolicy.RequestVersionExact,
        DefaultRequestVersion = new Version(2, 0),
      };

    using var channel = GrpcChannel.ForAddress(IPADDRESS, new GrpcChannelOptions { HttpClient = httpClient });


    var client = new PushNotificationService.PushNotificationServiceClient(channel);

    SubscriptionRequest subscriptionRequest = new SubscriptionRequest { RegistrationId = PushNotifications.registration_id };
    subscriptionRequest.Topics.Add(createTopics);

    var reply = client.subscribe(subscriptionRequest);
    try
    {
      await foreach (var subscriptionResponse in reply.ResponseStream.ReadAllAsync())
      {

        PushNotifications.notifications.Add(subscriptionResponse);
        
        //this.StateHasChanged();
        await InvokeAsync(StateHasChanged);
        await Task.Delay(1);
      }
    }
...
```

```
namespace GrpcStreamClient.Data
{
  public class PushNotifications
  {
    public string registration_id { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    public bool[] isChecked { get; set; } = new bool[3];
    public List<String> notifications { get; set; } = new List<string>();
  }
}
```

Comment: @Henk Holterman
When I press the button, subscribe() works. This is Server Streaming gRPC. I want to print it out on the screen as soon as the server sends me the stream. I will add that content.

Comment: @beginner `PushNotifications` variable data is it persistence? Is it accessible globally?

Comment: @Ibrahim Yes, it is persistence. If you go to another page and come back, the data inside the variable stays the same and stays on the screen. StateHasChanged() does not work only when you add a new variable.
As mentioned above, data is added to the variable, but only StateHasChanged() does not work. If an event such as clicking a button occurs and the screen is rendered, the added content is displayed on the screen normally.

Comment: @beginner Can you share more data on your object? I believe you need to implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface on your class to detect the changes. Also use `ObservableCollection` instead.

Comment: @Ibrahim Added class PushNotifications to content. Will this help?

Comment: @beginner Yes now better. I will check it and hopefully come with a solution after I reach my destination.

Comment: @HenkHolterman In fact, I'm not familiar with async. I wrote it like that because there was no example code and simply no return. That function calls once when the button is pressed, but it is constantly notified by the server by stream gRPC.

Comment: @Ibrahim https://coder-solution-es.com/solution-es-blog/1315149
I tried using this address method. It's a method of creating a new page and navigateto(). It seems to be the wrong way, but it behaves normally. Will this help you find a problem?

Comment: @beginner The issue is within the `subscribe` function. Can you increase the delay to 500ms eg. `await Task.Delay(500);`

Comment: @beginner Also replace `await foreach` in `subscribe` function to this instead: 
`var subscriptionResponse = await reply.ResponseStream.ReadAllAsync()
  foreach(var response in subscriptionResponse)
  {
 PushNotifications.notifications.Add(response);
  }
  StateHasChanged();`. Here it is better execute `StateHasChanged` after the loop. Hopefully it solves your issue. Let me know.

Comment: @Ibrahim  
await Task.Delay (500); doesn't seem to be working

Comment: @Ibrahim 
The method below results in an error. CS1061. `'IAsyncEnumerable<SubscriptionResponse>' does not contain a definition for 'GetAwaiter' and no accessible extension method 'GetAwaiter' accepting a first argument of type 'IAsyncEnumerable<SubscriptionResponse>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)`  Maybe IAsyncEnumerable can only be used as a wait in foreach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since I can't run your `subscribe` functions as it requires dependencies and other logic, I can recommend you use an event-based solution for updating notifications on the UI whenever a new one is added. Every page that listens to the event will be able to render the new notifications.

As for your grpc logic, you need to fix your code. Provide a function for subscribe and an event listener for incoming messages, that way when you have a new message you can invoke `NoticationsChanged` action implemented in the code below.

Follow the steps below to implement a `Singleton` service with a page that listens for updated notications. It should provide you a better structure to implement your solution.

```
// program.cs
builder.Services.AddSingleton<IMyService, MyService>();
```

Interface:

```
public interface IMyService
{
    PushNotifications pushNotifications { get; set; }
    event Action NotificationsChanged;
    void AddNotification();
    void Subscribe();
}
```

Service:

```
public class MyService: IMyService
{
    public PushNotifications pushNotifications { get; set; }
    public event Action NotificationsChanged;

    public MyService()
    {
        pushNotifications = new PushNotifications();
        Subscribe();
    }

    public void AddNotification()
    {
        var faker = new Faker("en"); // using Bogus;
        var notification = faker.Lorem.Sentence(10);

        pushNotifications.notifications.Add(notification);
        NotificationsChanged?.Invoke(); // invoke action when you add notification
    }

    async public void Subscribe()
    {
        //
    }
}
```

In your `Subscribe` function where you add notification, you can invoke the action like this:

```
pushNotifications.notifications.Add(subscriptionResponse);
NotificationsChanged?.Invoke(); // invoke action when you add notification
await Task.Delay(100);
```

NotificationPage1.razor: (change route and title for page 2)

```
@page "/"
@inject IMyService myService
@implements IDisposable

<PageTitle>Index</PageTitle>
<h1>Page 1</h1>

<ul>
    @foreach (var notification in myService.pushNotifications.notifications)
    {
        <li>@notification</li>
    }
</ul>

<button class="btn btn-primary"
        @onclick="@(() => myService.AddNotification())">
    Add Notification
</button>


@code {

    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        myService.NotificationsChanged += OnNotify;
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        myService.NotificationsChanged -= OnNotify;
    }

    private async void OnNotify()
    {
        try
        {
            await InvokeAsync(() => StateHasChanged())
            .ConfigureAwait(false);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            // log exception
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

[image: Output]

Comment: Wow, it's working properly. Thank you very much. I can only admire your outstanding ability. Thank you so much for preparing the perfect code and video for me. I understand the other part, ```public event action?``` I've never used this part before, so I'm a little confused. ```MyService.NotificationsChanged+=OnNotify;``` ```-= OnNotify;``` could you tell me what this means?
Once again, thank you very much.

Comment: @beginner, glad to hear that. `event Action` to me is an implementation of simple event where we don't worry about changing number or types of parameters or return back feedback. Within a page we need to subscribe to this event using the `+=OnNotify` when the page is initialized, and when the page is disposed, we also need to unsubscribe from the event using `-=`

Comment: @beginner when you subscribe to `OnNotify`, it means this method will be called when the event is invoked by adding new notification. `OnNotify` method then executes the `StateHasChanged`. You can subscribe to other methods not necessarily this.

Comment: I think it will be very useful not only this time but also in the future. Thank you so much for your kind reply!!

Comment: @beginner Its very nice to hear that. Thank you